# How to find the period of the sum of two trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry

I want to know if there exists a general method to find the period of the sum of two periodic trigonometric function. Example:

> $$f(x)=\cos(x/3)+\cos(x/4).$$

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! We like questions that tell us what you have already tried, so that we can give appropriate answers. Also, if you know that the definition of "period" has two parts, did you succeed in proving any of them?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164221/period-of-the-sum-product-of-two-functions

Comment: This also : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/681750/sum-of-two-periodic-functions-is-periodic

Answer (score 9):

The period of $\cos\dfrac xk$ is $2\pi k$

So, the period of $\cos\dfrac x3$ is $2\pi\cdot3$ and that of $\cos\dfrac x4$ is $2\pi\cdot4$

As $\dfrac{2\pi\cdot4}{2\pi\cdot3}=\dfrac43$ is rational

So, the period of $\cos\dfrac x3+\cos\dfrac x4$ will be a divisor of lcm$(6\pi,8\pi)=24\pi$

Now try with the divisors of $24$

Comment: Is there a proof of the LCM being the period?

Answer (score 0):

Pick $x=0$. Then $f(x)=2$ is the maximum of $f(x)$. The next time this occurs is when $x/3$ and $x/4$ are both multiples of $2\pi$. This will happen next at $24\pi$ ($12\pi$ makes $f(x)=0$)