# What is the period of $f(x) = \cos (x) \cos(2x) \cos(3x)$?

Tags: functions, relations, periodic-functions

What is the period of $f(x) = \cos(x) \cos(2x) \cos(3x)$?  Please tell me the method plus the logic behind solving these kind of problems .. Plus is there any property for even functions like even functions are always onto ?

Comment: You really need to learn to make titles more specific. If it ends in the number 5 because it's the 5th question about the same general topic you've asked... that's not good. I really don't see why you couldn't put the actual question in the title.

Comment: I highly encourage you to make a more meaningful title.

Comment: See: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164221/period-of-the-sum-product-of-two-functions

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/873723/how-to-find-the-period-of-the-sum-of-two-trigonometric-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
     \cos(3x - x) &= \cos 3x \cos x + \sin 3x \sin x \\
     \cos(3x + x) &= \cos 3x \cos x - \sin 3x \sin x \\
     \hline
     \cos x \cos 3x &= \dfrac 12 \cos 2x + \dfrac 12 \cos 4x \\
     \cos x \cos 3x &= \dfrac 12 \cos 2x + \dfrac 12 (2 \cos^2 2x - 1) \\
    \cos x \cos 3x &= \dfrac 12 \cos 2x + \cos^2 2x - \dfrac 12  \\
    \hline
    \cos x \cos 2x \cos 3x
    &= \dfrac 12 \cos^2 2x + \cos^3 2x - \dfrac 12 \cos 2x \\
\end{align}

The period is $\pi$.

Comment: Can there be a general direct shortcut for the period of functions in multiplication?

Comment: @Ujjwal - good question. I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

That the product has period $\pi$ is easily seen, once we prove $$\cos x\cos2x\cos3x =\frac{1}{4}\left(\cos6x+\cos4x+\cos2x+1\right).$$There are at least two quick ways to do this. One uses $\cos nx =\tfrac{1}{2}\left(z^n+z^{-n}\right)$ with $z:=e^{ix}$; the other uses $\cos A\cos B=\tfrac{1}{2}\left(\cos\left(A+B\right)+\cos\left(A-B\right)\right)$.

Edited for a more detailed explanation: the product is $$\tfrac{1}{8}\left(z+z^{-1}\right)\left(z^2+z^{-2}\right)\left(z^3+z^{-3}\right)=\tfrac{1}{8}\left(z^6+z^{-6}+z^4+z^{-4}+z^2+z^{-2}+2\right).$$The right-hand side is $\tfrac{1}{8}\left(2\cos 6x+2\cos 4x+2\cos 2x+2\right).$

Comment: Can you please explain to me the first method ?  I'm pretty weak with complex numbers ... So if you could please illustrate how to process with the first method ..

Comment: It might be a bit much for a comment, so I've expanded the answer somewhat.

Comment: How did you get 1/8 outside ? Shouldn't it be 1/6 according to the formula ? And is $z^6+z^{-6}$ equal to 2cos6x? If it is , then kindly explain how. My basics of complex numbers are not clear. Plus could you suggest me some posts on here where I can build up my concepts on complex numbers ?

Comment: @Ujjwal the $\tfrac{1}{8}$ factor is the product of three $\tfrac{1}{2}$ factors from $\cos nx=\tfrac{1}{2}\left(z^n+z^{-n}\right)$ for $n\in\left\{1,2,3\right\}$. The cases $n\in\left\{0,2,4,6\right\}$ allow the right-hand side to be rewritten in terms of cosines, including $\cos 0x=1$. I'm not sure what posts here would help you learn more; sorry.

Comment: What does the term $e^ix$ really signify ? And what do you mean by writing right hand side for n belonging to 0, 2, 4, 6?  And why do we take only even integrals?

Comment: And I didn't see the explanation properly now I got the reason for the existence of 1/8 outside.

Comment: @Ujjwal It can be shown that $\cos x + i\sin x = e^{ix}$. (Hint: the functions are equal at $x=0$; the derivative of their ratio can be shown to be $0$.) The relevant values of $n$ on each side of the equation are those for which $z^n+z^{-n}$ appears with some coefficient.