# Minimum period of function $3\sin(3x)+2\cos^{2}(x)$

Tags: trigonometry

Find the minimum period of the following function : $f(x) = 3\sin(3x) + 2\cos^{2}(x)$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/873723/how-to-find-the-period-of-the-sum-of-two-trigonometric-functions

Comment: Do you have a generality for this form ?

Comment: Informal approach: Use a graphing utility

Comment: So hard to creat its graph .

Comment: You can easily create the graph on-line at [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/).  Aside from looking at the graph, you can use trigonometric identities to put the function into a form where the period is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Use this fact $$\\\sin^{2k+1}(ax+b) \to T=\dfrac{2\pi}{|a|}\
\\\cos^{2k+1}(ax+b) \to T=\dfrac{2\pi}{|a|}\\$$
$$f(x) = 3sin3x + 2cos^{2}x\\
f(x) = 3sin3x + 2\frac{1+cos 2x}{2}=\\3sin 3x+1+cos 2x\\\to\begin{cases}sin 3x& T_1=\frac{2\pi}{3}\\cos 2x & T_2=\frac{2\pi}{2}\end{cases}$$now find l.c.m for $T_1,T_2$
$$T=\dfrac{\pi}{3}[2,3]=\dfrac{\pi}{3}\times 6=2\pi$$