# Prove $\alpha f + \beta g$ is periodic function with period LCM($\tau_1,\tau_2$).

Tags: real-analysis, functions, periodic-functions

Let $f$ be periodic with period $\tau_1$ and $g$ periodic  with period $\tau_2$, such that $\frac{\tau_1}{\tau_2} \in \mathbb{Q}$. Then prove
$\alpha f + \beta g$  is periodic function with period LCM($\tau_1,\tau_2$).

 I know what is intuitive idea why this works,but I have problem with trying to prove it. The biggest problem is question where to use  $\frac{\tau_1}{\tau_2} \in \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Don't you mean af+bg?

Comment: This may help you [Sum of two periodic functions is periodic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/681750/sum-of-two-periodic-functions-is-periodic).                                                                                         Check the second answer in the link, it has answer to your question.

Comment: I think I need a different type of proof then this in the link ...