# How to show that $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ defined as $f(x)=x$ can be decomposed as a sum of two periodic functions?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, axiom-of-choice

I read somewhere that the proof depends on AC.

But how about showing it explicitly i.e finding an explicit example that satisfies this?

I would like to see both proofs, the one that depends on AC and one that not (if it's possible).

Thanks!
N.B
I tried searching for it in google, but with no success.

Comment: @AsafKaragila check the old forum post here: http://www.tapuz.co.il/forums/viewmsg/457/12834712/%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%95%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%94_%D7%92%D7%91%D7%95%D7%94%D7%94/%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%9E%D7%98%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%94

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(This is based on [this blogpost](https://mathblag.wordpress.com/2013/09/01/sums-of-periodic-functions/), which I found through [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/684679/622).)

Pick a Hamel basis for $\Bbb R$ over $\Bbb Q$, that is a set of reals, $B$, such that every real number can be written as a unique linear combination of elements of $B$, with rational coefficients.

For $r\in B$ and $x\in\Bbb R$, let $x_r$ be the rational coefficient of $r$ in the linear combination resulting in $x$. Note that for all but finitely many $r$'s, it will be $0$. So in other words, $x=\sum_{r\in B}x_rr$ for every real number.

**Claim.** For a fixed $r$, the function $x\mapsto x_r r$ is periodic.

*Proof*. Note that if $r'\in B$ and $r'\neq r$, then $(x+r')_r=x_r$. $\square$

This easily generalises: if $A\subsetneq B$, then $x_A=\sum_{r\in A}x_r r$ is a well-defined function, and if $r\in B\setminus A$, then $x\mapsto x_A$ is periodic with period $r$.

Finally, we are ready to prove the claim about the identity function!

Fix $r\in B$, and let $f_1(x)=x_r r$, and $f_2(x)=x_{B\setminus\{r\}}$. Then $f_1+f_2=\operatorname{id}$, and by the above, both are periodic.

---

The axiom of choice was needed for obtaining the Hamel basis. Indeed, it is consistent without the axiom of choice that there is no such basis, in which case the above proof certainly does not work.

Of course, this is not a proof that the axiom of choice is required. One way to prove this is to show that any pair of periodic functions which can be added to the identity must be $\Bbb Q$-linearity, which under some conditions imply continuity, which means it is impossible. But I am not familiar with the theory of periodic functions enough to give you an answer off the cuff.

Comment: So if I assume $\not AC$ then I get that there are no such functions?

Comment: Assuming that choice fails tells you *nothing*. Just like saying that a set is finite tells you nothing about the size of the set, or what kind of elements are in that set. What I said is that *maybe* it is possible to prove that *it is possible* that with additional axioms, which contradict the axiom of choice (but not the rest of ZF), that maybe in these cases there is no such decomposition.

Comment: The task of proving that this proposition depends on the axiom of choice is very difficult : you have to exhibit some model of ZF(without choice) where $f$ can't be written as the sum of two periodic functions.

The proof given by Asaf above **relies** on AC. But to show that one can't find a proof of our proposition that doesn't use AC is another story.

Comment: @OlivierRoche so here's an interesting open problem to dwell on. :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm too lazy to compute a forcing doing this, but I would enjoy a sketch of a proof.

Comment: @Olivier: That sounds like fun.

Comment: @Olivier: I'm not sure how a forcing proof would look like. You maybe want to mimic the "nowhere differentiable continuous function", where we force with rational-based approximations, and then use absoluteness. But In that case we can rely on these rational-based approximation to be a ccc forcing; and we can use absoluteness due to continuity. In this case we have to approximate everywhere, and it's not obvious to me that this is a $\Pi^1_3$ statement, as the functions are not remotely continuous (in principle). So we're left with other type of approximations, but this is tantamount to Zorn.