# how to determine the smallest t when summing 2 periodic functions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry, periodic-functions

```
     This part answered :-
```

How does one determine what is $t$ when we have two trigonometric functions added to each other? Like $\tan(x) + \sin(2x)$
\begin{align}
\tan(x) &= \tan(x + \pi) \\
\sin(2x) &= \sin(2x + \pi) 
\end{align}

Do we take the $\pi$ as $t$ because they have it in common?

```
        Answered section end
```

Is the sum of trigonometric periodic function often periodic or always and why?(i would like to share my take on this one from what i read and   Deduced)

And how do we determine that this function is periodic and find $t$?
$$
\tan(x) \sin(3x)
$$
since
\begin{align}
\tan(x) &= \tan(x + \pi) \\
\sin(3x) & = \sin(2x + 2\pi/3)
\end{align}
And thx in advance

Comment: The period of the sum of 2 functions is the least common multiple of their period

Comment: It probably makes some sense to change the title to reflect you are interested in this question specifically over finite sums of periodic functions.

Comment: Will do , @Snared

Comment: @MathAttack Mind sharing some examples to make sure I understood correctly

Comment: @lodo There are numerous answers of varying technical detail posted on this related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/681750/sum-of-two-periodic-functions-is-periodic

Answer (score 0):

I read the resources above and tried to understand the two participants shares ,
I understand now how to determine t for the sum of two functions ,
As said above we try to find the least common multiple of their period .
for example:-

$\sin(2x) + \cos(3x)$
\begin{align}
\cos(3x) &= \cos(3x +2\pi/3)&=\cos(3x +tn)\\
\sin(2x) &= \sin(2x + \pi) &= \sin(2x +tm)\\
\end{align}
$m>0 ,n>0$ and they are whole numbers

So in this case we have the least common multiple when n is 3 and m is 2
Resulting in t equals $2\pi $ for the sum of the two functions .

I will try to share what I have deduced in regards to if the sum of two
Periodic functions is always periodic since I now have a slightly better understanding of the topic ,

The answer is **no**, there does not exist non zero integers $a$,$b$ such that $a t_1=bt_2$

For example cos($\pi x$)+sin($2x$).
We can see that $a \times 2=b \times \pi$
does not exist, Hence the answer is a non periodic function

If what I deduced is incorrect any correction is appreciated,

I am left with a couple of questions unanswered, I will try to edit the original version to highlight them.