# How to find period of these types of functions?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, signal-processing, periodic-functions

> Find a period of the following function.
>   $$x(t) = 2\cos(3\pi t) + 7\cos(9t).$$

After finding the individual time period how to proceed?

Comment: What makes you think that's periodic?

Comment: cause cos is a periodic function........?

Comment: @Sajal The sum of two periodic functions doesn't need to be periodic...

Comment: @Sajal That's not enough for an intuition, let alone a proof. In fact, your $x(t)$ isn't periodic, see for example  [The sum of two continuous periodic functions is periodic if and only if the ratio of their periods is rational?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356802/the-sum-of-two-continuous-periodic-functions-is-periodic-if-and-only-if-the-rati).

Comment: Dear @Sajal, welcome to Mathematics SE. For the future, include your question into the body, to help people read and understand your problem, and use the mathematics formatting, please. If you need some hint how to do it, have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). Moreover, it would be nice from you if you provide also some attempt you already tried to follow.

Comment: The periods of the terms have no common multiple so the period is $\infty$

Comment: @lasenH Thank you sir.

Comment: @lasenH `so the period is ∞` Sorry, but that makes no sense. A periodic function has a *finite* period by definition. If you meant to say that $\,x(t)\,$ is not periodic, then that's not the right way to say it.

Answer (score 2):

$T$ names a period of $f$ if $T>0$ and for all $x$ from domain $f$ we need $f(x+T)=f(T)$.

Also, if there is $T'>0$ with previous properties then $T'\geq T$.

Now, let $T$ is a period of our function.

Thus, for all $x$ we have:
$$f(x+T)=f(x),$$
where $f(x)=2\cos3\pi x+7\cos9x$ or
$$2\cos3\pi(x+T)+7\cos9(x+T)=2\cos3\pi x+7\cos9x.$$
Let $x=0$.

Thus, $$2\cos3\pi T+7\cos9T=9,$$
which gives $\cos3\pi T=1$ and $\cos9T=1$, which gives
$$T=\frac{2}{3}k,k\in\mathbb Z$$ and
$$T=\frac{2\pi}{9}m, m\in\mathbb Z,$$
which gives $\pi=\frac{3k}{m}$, which is absurd.

Thus, our function has no period.

Comment: This is just amazing.. Very nice explanations.. This is counter-intuitive if you try to plot and deduce from the plot because it seems to be periodic.