# Period of $f(x)=\sin(4x)+\cos(x\sqrt{2})$

Tags: trigonometry, periodic-functions

I have $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x)=\sin(4x)+\cos(x\sqrt{2})$ and I need to find the period of this function.
I found that the period of $\sin(4x)=\pi/2$ and the period of $\cos(x\sqrt{2})=\pi\sqrt{2}$.
Why doesn't this function have a period and how can I  approach the exercise?

Comment: WA says the function is not periodic

Comment: How to see that without a computer?

Comment: You can assume $$f(x)$$ is periodic, so $$f(x)=f(x+T)$$ and then you will get a contradiction

Comment: For $$x=0$$ you would get $$f(0)=f(T)$$

Comment: Or a different, more general solution: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356802/the-sum-of-two-continuous-periodic-functions-is-periodic-if-and-only-if-the-rati

Comment: @Botond Not really a duplicate, as this one mixes sin and cos terms. Of course, the general solution will be applicable here as well.

Comment: @Ingix you are right, but Hagen's answer in the linked question totally covers it.

Comment: Because this "periodic" function is composed of two other periodic functions, one of period $2\pi$ and the other of period $\sqrt{2}\pi$ then if this function were periodic, it would repeat every time both of these functions reach the end of a repeat at the same point. So $2\pi n=\sqrt{2}\pi m$ where $n$ and $m$ are the number of repeats. I think if no integers $m$ and $n$ exist that satisfy this equation then it is not periodic

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/873723/how-to-find-the-period-of-the-sum-of-two-trigonometric-functions